# Auto Populate a textbox on an Access form with PhoneContacts from a table field whenever checkboxes are selected

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to build an MS Access database that can be used to send bulksms. 
The problem am facing has to do with how the recipient textbox (ttcontact) on a form can be populated with phone numbers (separated with commas)  when they are checked in checkboxes.

Image of Form

[image: Image of Form]

I researched a little and was able to come up with the vba codes below but they only display the latest contact checked in the checkbox

```
Private Sub Select_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Select.Value = True Then
Me.ttContact.Value = Me.MobilePhone.Value
' etc.
Else: Me.ttContact.Value = Null
End If
End Sub
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add the data, you need to concatenate it to the existing contents of `ttContact`. And rather than setting `ttContact` to Null when trying to remove the data, you need to use the `Replace` function. I've modified your code:

```
Private Sub Select_Click()
    If Me.Select = True Then
        If InStr(Me!ttContact, Me!MobilePhone) = 0 Then '   only add if not already present
            Me!ttContact = Me!ttContact & "," & Me!MobilePhone
        End If
    Else
        Me!ttContact = Replace(Nz(Me!ttContact, ""), "," & Me!MobilePhone, "")
        Me!ttContact = Replace(Nz(Me!ttContact, ""), Me!MobilePhone & ",", "")
    End If
    If Left(Me!ttContact, 1) = "," Then Me!ttContact = Mid(Me!ttContact, 2)
    If Right(Me!ttContact, 1) = "," Then Me!ttContact = Left(Me!ttContact, Len(Me!ttContact) - 1)
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: The solution worked when i clicked on the individual checkboxes. But when i click Select All button, nothing displays in the ttcontact control even though the boxes will be checked alright

Comment: You will need a separate piece of code in the command button's Click event. I would suggest setting ttContact to an empty string, and then using a recordset to get the required contact details.